# Frequencies for Bass Guitar EQing

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, mixing, frequency

As a hobbiest musician I am writing and recording songs in my home studio; mainly rock, funk and smooth jazz. My primary instrument is the bass guitar where I send a Line Out on my amp to my Audio Interface which is connected to my Win 11 PC.

My DAW has an 8-band equalizer, 5 of which have Q and Gain adjustments. Below are the frequencies that I have guessed at that seem relatively effective. I want to settle on a standard set of frequencies to quicken my workflow. My workflow is to first Compress my bass track then EQ my bass with all other instruments muted and then verify the EQ with all instruments un-muted.

My question is, are there a set of frequencies for bass guitar EQing that will allow me to more crisply hear (compared to what I show below) the effect of Q and Gain adjustments when using headphones when I mix?

LLC: 50Hz

LC: 50Hz

LF: 50Hz, Q, Gain

LMF: 80Hz, Q, Gain

MF: 300HZ, Q, Gain

HMF: 600Hz, Q, Gain

HF: 800Hz, Q, Gain

HC: 1000Hz

I also have an overall Gain adjustment for my bass track and volume automation for each track in the mix.

Any web resources or other suggestions that address this would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  "are there a set of frequencies for bass guitar EQing that will allow me to more crisply hear ... the effect of Q and Gain adjustments..." The effect of gain adjustments will be most noticeable when the band center is at a frequency that is loud in the original signal.  The effect of Q adjustments will be most noticeable when the band center is near (but not at) a frequency that is loud in the original signal.  Neither of these facts are useful for eqing your bass track, but they might be helpful if you're trying to learn to use the eq.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for an "eq cheat sheet" for bass guitar?  Not that they're super helpful... but people sure do ask for them a lot.

Comment: "I want to settle on a standard set of frequencies to quicken my workflow" - always using the same frequencies won’t quicken your workflow. It will just limit the quality of your mixes. It’s like asking what are the best 7 notes to use to write a song so you can always use those notes when you write every song.

Comment: "volume automation for each track in the mix" if you want to quicken your workflow stop doing this. Automating levels is only worth the effort for the most important 1-3 tracks in a mix. Like lead vocals and *maybe* a solo. If you really can’t make the mix sound decent with just EQ and compression then you’ve got challenges that fader automation won’t really fix anyway. If your production and recording process is good, then just bringing all the faders up to somewhere between -12 and -3 should be a working mix that is just a bit lifeless but otherwise ok.

Comment: Check this out instead, there’s even a chart of frequency ranges and what they sound like: https://mastering.com/approach-equalization-two-types-eq/

Comment: "Cheat sheet"? Sure. So long as the sheet captures the essence of EQing bass guitar.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox Thanks for the web link. This is a huge subject and the website you provided is huge. This will take time to digest.

Comment: Mixing is as deep an art and takes a similar amount of time and effort to learn as playing bass or any other instrument.

Comment: Also factor in the quality of cans you use. There are so many factors involved, and one 'ideal' setting just won't cut the mustard. Using one tone constantly is also boring. The question itself is flawed, thus dv.

Comment: Two points… 1) Only EQ what needs EQing - that's not going to be the same twice. There is no template for EQ, there's only *ears*. 2) Don't mix on cans. Ever. Cans are for tracking, proper monitors are for mixing.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good advice on only EQing what needs EQing. I guess I assumed there could be a useful template for the bass in that it is a relatively spectrally-consistent  (boring in a good way) instrument as opposed to EQing a male and female vocal duet where the tones can vary greatly. Because of this and because I have locked-in my amp model I'm thinking that a template of 8 frequencies could meet my needs, since years ago only 3 or less were used. I do have a good set of studio monitors but I find I can detect more nuance with my cans, so I use both in my workflow.

Comment: Personally, I like to get my sound right on the way in. At mix all I'm likely to do is pull a bit at 250 if it's causing confusion with anything else, or some at 125 for the same reason - if it's arguing with the kick. I'm equally likely to pull the lows from guitars instead, so there's still no fixed pattern. It depends what function everything is performing.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I agree. The source of my problem might be what is coming out of my amp and thus, what is sent to my DAW. When I'm playing and recording I'm focussed on my fingers and what I'm hearing in the rest of the band; assuming I can always clean up my tone  downstream in my DAW. I think, I'll tweek my amp model and EQ to really get what I really like. And in the bargain I may find no more hiss. The other thing I'm learning is that even though I'm not seeking perfection (as I define it) that each EQ effort is a unique activity. I was hoping some level of "cookie-cutter" would be possible.

Comment: Can you get into the control room to listen, when your amp is rigged up? My old live rig has a DI-out, which always made it easy. Get a good sound in the studio, it would be even better in the control room. I used to keep the amp in the studio & invite all bassists to give it a go before rigging their own up. No-one ever used their own amp after trying mine;) [Early 80s Dynacord BS412 I've owned since nearly new.] My current amp is just a Line6 UX2 interface - so I only ever hear it over the studio monitors.

Comment: No - that's the room your desk & monitors are, as opposed to the studio, which is where the drum kit & amps go ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Not sure what you mean by "control room", is that software? My amp is the 40W Fender Bronco and I'm using the "Rumble" preset bass model on it.; I also wear flatwounds. And to tell you the truth I think the tone is pretty good in my studio. I don't hear the hiss when I play a solo riff, so I certainly don't hear it when I'm jamming along with the band

Comment: I'm getting a message about avoiding extended discussions.

Comment: "I assumed there could be a useful template for the bass in that it is a relatively spectrally-consistent (boring in a good way) instrument as opposed to EQing a male and female vocal duet where the tones can vary greatly." - This assumption is probably causing problems with your mixing style. The assumption is false. Bass guitar is no more timbrally consistent than electric guitar. In other words, the range of possible bass guitar tones is incredibly vast - greater than the difference among different singing voices.

Answer (score 0):

> My DAW has an 8-band equalizer, 5 of which have Q and Gain adjustments.

You can easily find an EQ with more bands, or stack several EQs in series. I'm not saying that you need more bands, but this shouldn't be a limitation.

> Below are the frequencies that I have guessed at that seem relatively effective.

You seem to neglect frequencies of several kHz, which affect the presence of the instrument in the mix.

> My workflow is to first Compress my bass track then EQ my bass with all other instruments muted and then verify the EQ with all instruments un-muted.

Some remarks:

1. Sometimes it is useful to apply EQ before the compressor, because it affects how the compressor reacts.
2. If you set dynamics without hearing other instruments, you may also need to review it in the full mix.
3. Bass, especially in rock styles, may benefit from parallel processing. Note that e.g. bass overdrive pedals, unlike guitar pedals, often mix the clean and overdriven signals.

Comment: I'm thinking that 8-bands are plenty for my needs. Or at the minimum I'd like to first fully understand these 8 before going with more. Yes I am neglecting frequencies higher than 1kHz because I have unwanted hiss much above this freq., thus I high-cut at 1kHz. Plus I generally go after the deep rich tones and rarely play high on the fretboard. I understand that the prevailing wisdom is to Compress and then EQ. I'm not using any pedals but my amp does have EQ and several bass models onboard.

Comment: Are you using a high impedance input on your interface?  You should not have so much hiss that you feel the need to high cut at 1kHz.

Comment: @Steve Eight bands are actually too many for your needs. If you use more than four you might be doing something that’s making it harder to mix, not easier. Most of the greatest recordings in history were mixed with no more than four bands of EQ of each track, and many with fewer or none. Instead of asking for specific frequencies, do some web searches on how to EQ a track and start practicing. It’s experience and skill, not knowing certain frequencies, that makes a good mix.

Comment: @Steve Oh I just read you’re high cutting at 1 kHz. There are bass tones that don’t need anything above 900 or 1000 Hz, but there are other tones that really DO need stuff around 1.2 or 2.5 or 5 kHz. I suggest figuring out where the hiss is coming from and dealing with that before getting lost in strange EQ strategies.

Comment: @Edward. I'm not sure if I'm using high impedance or not. My interface has an Instrument, Mic/Line and +48V selectable switch. I'm using "Instrument".

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes I am high cutting at 1kHz mainly because of the hiss I hear when I mute all other instruments. When the other instruments are in, the hiss is not detectable. But also, and for the song I'm mixing, there is no useful bass info beyond 1kHz. There is nothing detectable  except the hiss (and other annoying artifacts) up there. So why wouldn't I filter the unwanted noise out?

Comment: @Steve I think right now your productivity and sound quality would benefit more from fixing the high pitched noise than fine tuning EQ. Have you tried plugging the guitar directly into the interface, without using the amp?

Comment: @Steve I’m not trying to say you shouldn’t EQ the way you are. It is a good example of why we can’t give you specific frequencies. A lot of **other** bass sounds (not yours) have important info above 1 kHz, so if I did try to give you a list of frequency ranges, 2-4 of them would be above 1 kHz and would be useless to you. Also I suggest you not be satisfied to cut at 1 kHz and not worry about it. If the hiss is that loud there is probably some problem in your signal chain that could be causing other problems beside the hiss. Figure out why there’s hiss and you might get a better tone.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, there are a lot of frequencies other than those coming from my bass that are important and are above 1kHz. This is why I'm not high-cutting any of those instruments; only my bass. I'm not sure you fully understand that. So when I ask for a set of frequencies in the OP, these frequencies only apply to EQing my bass recordings. And yes, there should be no hiss, so I do have a problem in my signal chain; probably in my amp but that needs to be investigated.

Comment: @ToddWilcox UPDATE: To sharpen my point above, I muted all instruments except my bass. Then I disengaged all EQing on the bass track except for the Low-cut filter, and changed it's frequency to 1kHz with a 48db/oct roll. This only allows frequencies above 1kHz to get thru. And what do I hear? Mainly the hiss (sounds like white noise or rain falling) and a very faint outline of the notes I'm playing. I would describe these notes as "finger artifacts" and are so faint they would never be audible to a human in the mix. So there is no useful bass info above 1kHz in this particular track.

Comment: @Steve How would we know what frequencies apply to EQing your bass recordings? I understand that you’re only low passing the bass at 1 kHz. Maybe you’re not understanding that your choice to do that is particular to **your** bass sound and that would not be good general guidance for all bass sounds?